# Override escape functionality in jinja2

Tags: jinja2

By default, jinja2 offers escape functionality for html. I am however trying to (ab)use the templating engine for latex documents, which means that the html escaping is not really useful. Instead I would like to implement some sort of (basic) latex escaping.

So the question is: How can I override the jinja2.escape() function?

I tried doing something like

```
import jinja2.utils
def latex_escape(test):
    print(test)
    return 'dummystring'
jinja2.utils.escape = latex_escape
```

but this doesn't work at all